# multiple dates validation in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to validate if multiple timestamps are distinct ,comma separated and in correct format 'yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm'.

case 1 -

```
'2016-02-23-10-02','2017-01-24-11-05', '2017-02-23-11-05', '2016-02-23-10-02'
```

case 2 -

```
 '2016-02-23-10-02' '2017-01-24-11-05' '2017-01-89'
```

edit - added set later

```
def get_input(timestamps):
    unique_timestamps = set(timestamps)
    for i in unique_timestamps:
        try:
           datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
        except ValueError:
        #raise error
```

Comment: is this even a question? the code is working perfectly fine

Comment: I need validation for multiple timestamps are separated by commas and distinct.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the distinct, properly formatted timestamps you can use a python `set`:

`timestamps [ <list of unformatted timestamps> ]
distinct = set(map(get_input, timestamps))`

Comment: Thanks , I also need to check if timestamps are comma separated.